# Laravel 5.3 - Data inserting issue in MySQL 5.7.1

Tags: mysql, laravel-5.3

While inserting data from Laravel 5.3 it doesn't show up in the MySQL 5.7.1 database. I was following a tutorial, the teacher was using Laravel 5.2  Is that an issue?
Any help would be appreciated.

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
       // validate the data
       $this->validate($request, array(
           'title' => 'required|max:255',
           'body'  => 'required'
       ));

       // store in the database
       $post = new Post;

       $post->title = $request->title;
       $post->body = $request->body;

       $post->save();
       // Session::flash('success', 'The blog post was successfully save!');
       return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);
   }
```

Adding the whole code here...

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Post;
use Session;


class PostController extends Controller
{
/**
 * Display a listing of the resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function index()
{

    $posts = Post::all();
    return view('posts.index')->withPosts($posts);
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
    //
    return view('posts.create');
 }

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // validate the data
    $this->validate($request, array(
            'title' => 'required|max:255',
            'body'  => 'required'
        ));

    // store in the database
    $post = new Post;

    $post->title = $request->title;
    $post->body = $request->body;

    $post->save();

    return redirect()->route('posts.show', $post->id);


}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $post = Post::find($id);
    return view('posts.show')->withPost($post);
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{

}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code that is not working and we can try and take a look?

Comment: @Monkeybrain code added, thanks for having a look at this.

Comment: Are you getting any errors or warnings when you run the code? Is everything namespaced correctly (e.g. is App\Post declared ?)

Comment: @Monkeybrain no warning, no error, we are able to see records on the index page but no record in the database. Everything is done correct.

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code? Also try $post = new App\Post, instead of $post = new Post;

Comment: @Monkeybrain ok got it will update now.

Comment: Stupid question: are you saving to the correct database? If you see the records, they are saved

Comment: @nXu yes made sure its the correct one.

Comment: Which tutorial were you working from? Can you post a link?

Comment: @Monkeybrain [link] (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5j3fgiaSK4E)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your $fillable array is populated.

```
<?php
namespace App;

class Post extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['title', 'body'];
    ...
}
```